# Как правильно передать содежимое корзины в ссылку для телеграм бота

Tags: php, telegram

Есть форма заказа на сайте, с корзиной. Подскажите как передавать корректно содержимое корзины в ссылку для телеграм-бота. При таком коде, в строке "заказ" в телегу прилетает сообщение-каша:

```
Заказ: [{"id":"","name":"Пирожное Тирамису
550гр","image":"images/tiramisu.jpg","count":1,"price":440},{"id":"","name":"Торт
Наполеон 400гр","image":"images/napoleon.jpeg","count":1,"price":590}]
```

А нужно:

```
Заказ: Пирожное Тирамису 550гр 1 х 440 Торт Наполеон 400гр 1 х 590
```

Такой код:

```
<?php

//Переменная $name,$phone, $adress,$cart получает данные при помощи метода POST из формы
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];
$cart = []; //раскрываем содержимое переменной
  try {
    $json = json_decode($_POST["cart"], true);
    foreach ($json as $item) {
      if (empty($item["name"])) continue;
      $cleaned = [
        "name" => cleanValue($item["name"]),
        "adress" => cleanValue($item["adress"]),
        "count" => cleanValue(($item["count"])) ?: 1,
        "price" => cleanValue($item["price"]) ?: 0,
      ];

      $cart [] = $cleaned;

    }

//в переменную $token нужно вставить токен, который нам прислал @botFather

$token = "***********:********************************";

//нужна вставить chat_id (Как получить chad id, читайте ниже)

$chat_id = "-****************";

//Далее создаем переменную, в которую помещаем PHP массив

$arr = array(

  'Имя пользователя: ' => $name,

  'Телефон: ' => $phone,

  'Адрес:' => $adress,

  'Заказ:' => $cart

);

//При помощи цикла перебираем массив и помещаем переменную $txt текст из массива $arr

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {

  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";

};

//Осуществляется отправка данных в переменной $sendToTelegram

$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В 'Заказ:' нужно подавать не массив, а отформатированые данные

```
$cart_formated = [];
foreach($cart as $item){
    $cart_formated[] = "{$item['name']} {$item['count']} x {$item['price']}";
}
$cart_formated = implode(' ', $cart_formated);

$arr = array(

  'Имя пользователя: ' => $name,

  'Телефон: ' => $phone,

  'Адрес:' => $adress,

  'Заказ:' => $cart_formated

);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, работает. Возник второй вопрос: как реализовать вывод так, чтобы был перенос строки между позициями заказа? Сейчас все выдает в одну строку.

Comment: Для этого нужно сменить разделитель указанный в implode. Т.к. `parse_mode=html`, то должна сработать замена пробела на `<br/>`